# Attempting to factor $6g-7g-5$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification

When factoring $6g-7g-5$, would the answer be $(2g-1) (3+5)$? And would I check by distribution because if so the check would come out to $6g+10g-3-5$.

Comment: I'm really confused...are you actually trying to factor $6g-7g-5$?

Comment: As @induktio said, this doesn't make sense unless you add alot more context...

Comment: Correction: I should be factoring 6g^2 - 7g - 5

Comment: Welcome to the site, @Austin. You can format your mathematical expressions by placing them between dollar signs. For example, `$6g^2 - 7g - 5$` becomes $6g^2 - 7g - 5$.

Comment: @Austin To expand on Theophile's comment regarding formatting, if you plan on using MSE more, I'd *strongly* recommend perusing the [formatting tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19301/an-example-of-a-great-explanation-article-on-a-math-concept).

Comment: Then fix your question, don't post the correction in a comment.

Comment: And while editing your question you should also add ([tag:quadratics]) tag.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean $6g^2-7g-5$, then the answer is $(2g-1)(3g+5)$. You have the right idea; just make sure to check your details carefully.

On the other hand, if the question really is to factor $6g-7g-5$, then notice that this is just $-g-5$ (because $6g-7g=-g$), and there's nothing more to do.

Comment: Just an observation--there seem to be *so* many things wrong with OP's question post that I don't know if it really warrants any answers (kudos for providing one though). The question is meaningless if the problem is to factor $6g-7g-5$ and if the problem is to factor $6g^2-7g-5$, then I don't know how the OP got where he did other than simply copying a homework problem incorrectly. Thoughts?

Comment: @induktio In general, I would agree, but in this case I made an educated guess based on OP's previous question, which was also about factoring a quadratic with the $x^2$ term greater than $1$.

Comment: Ah, I see. Then extra kudos for doing some diligence there. Nice. (+1)

Comment: Well, I guess I'll show you my train of thought. The problem was $6g-7g-5$ so I multiplied a(c) to get -30. I found $10*-3$ as the common factor and plugged it into the equation to get $6g+10g-3g-5$ And found the GCF's to be $2g$ and -1. This lead to $6g(3+5) -(3+5)$ which led to $(2g-1) (3g+5)$ checking using FOIL I got $6g^2+10g-1-5$ which obviously isn't correct.

Comment: You are leaving off that square a lot ... $6g^2+10g-3g-5 \text{ now factor by grouping...} \\ \text{ the first two terms have } 2g \text{ in common so you can factor out a } \\  2g \text{ from the first two terms so doing that gives } 2g(3g+5)-3g-5 \text{ now the last two terms are } -3g \text{ and } -5 \\  \text{ you can say there common factor is either 1 or -1 but -1 would help here so much more } 2g(3g+5)-1(3g+5) \text{ which gives } (2g-1)(3g+5) \text{ so your answer is right } \\ \text{ now let's check it } 2g(3g+5)-1(3g+5) \\ 6g^2+10g-3g-5 \\ 6g^2+7g-5 $

Comment: also sorry I don't know how to make new lines

Comment: @Austin Before using a technique, always check to see if it's appropriate. If you really had $6g-7g-5$, then you can see that there's no $g^2$ term, so you don't need to factor at all. Or, for example, if the problem had been $6g^{3}-7g-5$, you again wouldn't be able to use your factoring technique because of the $g^3$ term.