# A question about using the squeeze theorem?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

If you have the inequalities not equal to, but the function is just strictly between two other functions, can you use the squeeze theorem?

Comment: $\text{ Do you mean instead of } \\ h(x) \le f(x) \le g(x) \\ \text{ you have } \\ h(x) <f(x)<g(x) \text{ ? }$

Comment: yes, that's it.

Comment: $ \le \text{ does mean less than or equal to } \\ \text{ so if you have } h(x) \le f(x) \le g(x) \text{or if you have } \\ h(x) <f(x)<g(x) \\ \text{ then as long as you have } \lim_{x \rightarrow a} g(x)=\lim_{x \rightarrow a} h(x)=L \\ \text{ then you can apply the squeeze theorem }$

Comment: Then you can use it, yes, because if you have $h(x) < f(x) < g(x)$, you have necessarily $h(x)\leq f(x) \leq g(x)$

Comment: Quantifiers are important!  Perhaps you have $h(x) < f(x) < g(x)$ for all $x$ in some *punctured* interval $[x_0, x_1] \setminus \{a\}$?

Comment: @randomgirl but how would that make sense if limit h(x)=L and limit g(x)=L then the inequality is not valid because f(x) is not less then nor greater then L, it is not valid to say f(x)<h(x) for example

Comment: Take $1-1/n < 1 < 1+1/n$. In the limit we get $1 \leq 1 \leq 1$. No problems there.

Comment: Pretend you have h(x)=-x^2 when x doesn't equal 0. Pretend you have g(x)=x^2 when x doesn't equal 0. Pretend you have f(x)=0 when x doesn't equal 0. Then h(x)<f(x)<g(x)

Comment: Like for my example I just posted. h(x) and f(x) and g(x) are never equal. But the lim as x approaches 0 of either h or g is 0. And we also have lim as x approaches 0 of f is also 0 by squeeze theorem. And yes I know squeeze theorem is not needed for this simple example but it can be applied.

Comment: does that answer your question @LearningMath ?

Comment: @randomgirl Please don't wrap entire comments in MathJax – it causes excessive flickering and page breaking while those comments are rendered. And newlines should not be used in comments, either. Comments should be compact in order to keep the focus on the main content, which are the question and the answers.

Comment: I experience no flickering. I'm sorry you do. Comments should be in order? What? I'm having trouble understanding that @epimorphic

Comment: @randomgirl "In order" is a synonym for "so that". What I meant is that comments should conserve space as much as possible, because not doing so creates visual noise. Look at your first two comments – see how much whitespace there is?

Comment: @randomgirl [This](http://i.stack.imgur.com/aFJMX.png) is what I briefly see on my screen whenever I click "show more comments" or post a comment. It's caused by the length of the math block in your second comment. See your comment [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1131409/attempting-to-factor-6g-7g-5/1131412#comment2309407_1131412) for a more permanent example.

Comment: I only did that because it was doing some weird thing if I didn't type it all as one mathjax thingy in the answer area. So I thought it would do the same in the comment area. @epimorphic Just tested it. It seems no weird things happen in the comment area.

Answer (score 16):

Remember,  if you have a fact "A", then you also have the fact "A or B",  for any fact B.   So, in this case,  if you have "$x<y$" then you have $x\le y$ because that's just shorthand for $x<y$ OR $x=y$,  and since we have $x<y$, then we have $x\le y$.  So yes,  strict inequality is just fine, as that's even better than less than or equal to.

Answer (score 0):

As Alan points out, strict inequality is fine. I think there are some elementary, intuitive observations that needs to be made. Suppose you have functions $f$ and $g$ such that some limit $\lim f$ and $\lim g$ exists and coincide. Suppose moreover that $f < h < g$. Taking limits of all functions you get $$\lim f \le \lim h \le \lim g = \lim h$$ What can you say about $\lim h$?

Answer (score -1):

Sorry for the late answer but just answering in case anyone else has the same doubt.

by looking at the question ,it seems that the op is wondering if $f(x) < g(x) < h(x)$ how can it be possible that the limits are equal as the functions are not allowed to be equal
The fact is $$f(x) < g(x) \implies \lim_{x\to a}f(x) \leq \lim_{x\to a}g(x) $$
this can be easily proved by taking h(x)=f(x)-g(x) and h(x)<0,now apply $\epsilon-\delta$ definition ,u cant rule out the possibility of $lim_{x\to a} h(x)=0$ and now u can use limit law to split f(x) and g(x) and hence proving the original statement
Several examples showing such scenario are provided in comments section.

Now coming to squeeze theorem,now u are possibly understanding that even if u have strict inequalities for the functions,it translates to having non strict inequalities for the limit and hence when the lower and upper bound for $\lim_{x \to a} g(x)$ are equal and it is allowed to take that value,it must take that value

alternatively, if u want to prove squeeze theorem for strict inequality from scratch ie. from $\epsilon -\delta $  definition , then proceed as shown in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem#Proof and just remove equality wherever necessary