# Why is Squeeze theorem with ≤/≥, rather than </>?

Tags: limits

Why is Squeeze theorem with $≤ or ≥$, rather than $< or >$?

It does work with < or > right? Since ≤ and ≥ include < and > correspondingly.

Additionally, surely one can use
$$g(x) < f(x) ≤ h(x)$$ 
$$or$$
$$g(x) ≤ f(x) < h(x)$$

as well?

---

I think this is more clearly formulated question than:
[A question about using the squeeze theorem?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1178711/a-question-about-using-the-squeeze-theorem)

Comment: The simplest option is to use $\leqslant$ and/or $\geqslant$ (consider what happens if $f(x)<g(x)<h(x)$ at some point $x$ such that $f(x)=g(x)$)..

Comment: If you use "$<$" instead of "$\leq$" in the squeeze theorem you are going to make it week not strong. So of course the original squeeze theorem will imply this weaker theorem.

Comment: "Being a more clearly formulated question" isn't enough to not be considered as a duplicate. If you think the question I linked is unclear (I don't think so and the people who answered it were able to understand it), feel free to suggest edits to it. We don't need two questions that ask exactly the same thing. (And I don't mean to offend, but your own question could be much clearer.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it works with either, with a caveat: if both of the functions you're bounding by attain the limit, you run into a contradiction. For instance, suppose $$g(x) < h(x) < f(x)$$ for all $x$, and $f(x) \to c$, $g(x) \to c$. If there is ever actually an $x$ where $g(x) = f(x) = c$, then you get $c < h(x) < c$, which is impossible. This is why we usually use $\leq$ and $\geq$, because it makes that contradiction impossible, and we don't actually need the strict inequality.

Answer (score 0):

The theorem is that if $f(x)\leq g(x)\leq h(x)$ , then $L = \lim\limits_{x\to c}f(x)\leq \lim\limits_{x\to c} g(x)\leq \lim\limits_{x\to c} h(x) = L$ means $\lim\limits_{x\to c} g(x)=L$ .

However, if $f(x)< g(x)< h(x)$ , then $L = \lim\limits_{x\to c}f(x)< \lim\limits_{x\to c} g(x)< \lim\limits_{x\to c} h(x) = L$ would mean $\lim\limits_{x\to c} g(x)$ does not exist.   As the limit cannot be simultaneously less and greater than $L$, it is squeezed out of existance.

Comment: If $f(x) < g(x) < h(x)$, then $\lim f(x) \color{red}{\le} \lim g(x) \color{red}{\le} \lim h(x)$... Strict inequalities become *not* strict when you take the limit. Take the example of $1 - 1/n < 1 < 1 + 1/n$. Your post makes no sense and is going to confuse all the students that read it.